# How to schedule 3 events to notify user via (notification bar) in android which runs even when my app is not running

Tags: android, events, background, notifications, scheduled-tasks

i have designed a news app where in i have to alert the user at 3 times in a day selected by the user.

The alert is done via android notification which i can code but i am not able to figure out how to schedule those 3 tasks and note this should alert user even when user is not running my app

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the AlarmManager for precise time events, or JobSchedulers when timing is not that important.
For the alarmmanager, use this tutorial:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTaskScheduling/article.html

And for the in-app notifications do this:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidNotifications/article.html

This is guarantied to work. Any question send me a private message.
Hope it helps!